# How to Remove HTML Elements from Post Excerpt?

Tags: wordpress, post

I am Using the Following Code and want to remove HTML All Elements.

```
<?php $exerpttext = substr(get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID), 0, 300);
if (!empty($exerpttext)) { echo $exerpttext.'....'; }  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `get_post_field` you can use `get_the_excerpt` which give you a string and will remove all the HTML tags. (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/)

However you can use `wp_strip_all_tags` to strip all HTML tags including script and style.
You can read more about `wp_strip_all_tags`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/

```
<?php $excerpttext = substr( wp_strip_all_tags( get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID ) ), 0, 300 );
if ( !empty( $excerpttext )) { echo $excerpttext).'....'; }  ?>
```

Comment: get_the_excerpt in this way we would fill the excerpt field in every post. I need to get auto Excerpt, that's why I am using this function.

Comment: get_the_excerpt defaults to pulling post_content if no excerpt is found. However, Khurram also included a way with your requested code as well.

Comment: This works, but it does not strip shortcodes, and it does not respect custom excerpts. So we should replace `get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID)` by `get_the_excerpt()`

Comment: In theory, `get_the_excerpt` should already remove tags, but currently, it doesn't (block theme in WordPress 6.2)